# How to Use PHP text-box value in PHP variable, without page reload and without using JavaScript (Ajax)

Tags: php, session, textbox

This textbox value set from javascript, and value set properly.

```
<input type="text" name="BillId" id="BillId" > /* this textbox value like (20,22,30,23)
```

Now 'BillId' textbox value used in as php variable.
Using session working not proper because the page does not reload.

This textbox value use in foreach loop

```
$variable = **hear use BillId textBox value**;
$var=explode(',',$variable);
echo $_SESSION['my'];
foreach($var as $row){  
       echo $row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done - it is important to understand that PHP is a server side script language. You can't make such a server side script responsive to client-side changes (such as the HTML input) without sending additional requests (such as page reloads or AJAX calls).

Why are extra requests not allowed for your use-case? And can what you want to do in the PHP backend not be done in a frontend javascript framework such as React or Vue?

Comment: Glad to be able to help! Please note that you can accept answers to mark a question as closed on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Without page reload and ajax, server side data can not changed.
In this case i used html and php both... so according to requirement in ajax set our html data and sent to user side.
Thanks!!!